# How can others connect on my AHKsocket winsock server? External IP?

Tags: connection, ip, autohotkey, tcp, winsock2

Using [AHKsock](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/53827-ahksock-a-simple-ahk-implementation-of-winsock-tcpip/) (AutoHotkey), I built a minimalistic client-server system with `AHKsock_Connect`, `AHKsock_Send` and `AHKsock_Listen` on **both sides** to communicate with each other. It works and I can send messages back and forth, if I connect to the server using `localhost`.

But I want the server to be accessible from everywhere. Shouldn't this be possible using my "external IP" which I can see @ [whatIsMyIP.com](http://whatIsMyIP.com)? Whenever someone tries to connect to the server on my computer, his/her connection will timeout/not work.

What is the IP of my server? How can others connect to it from anywhere? I assume there must be a simple solution to it, because the software itself seems to work: As stated above, connecting from the same computer to `localhost` will work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you forward the appropriate ports in your router/firewall? The IP should be correct.

Comment: I forward the port there, but all clients would have to do it, too, right? cause if they don't, how could I reach them..?

Comment: Oh, yeah if they're both sending and listening all parties have to forward the ports. If you had a server-client setup only the server would have to forward.

Comment: ok it seems to work now, after forwarding the port

Comment: Close the question with an answer :)

Comment: hm, although it was sidola who told me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did you forward the appropriate ports in your router/firewall? The IP should be correct.

This was the solution, I did something wrong in my router